# Reload Webpage in Google Chrome until HTML contains specific text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, applescript, loading, automator

This code works for Safari (reload webpage till HTML contains specific text).
**How to fix it for Chrome?**

```
tell application "Safari"

set keyword to "Authentication mail"
repeat
    set myWindow to current tab of first window
    activate
    
    do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in myWindow
    
    repeat while (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is not "complete"
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    
    set pageContent to do JavaScript ("window.document.documentElement.outerHTML") in myWindow
    
    if pageContent contains keyword then
        beep beep beep
        exit repeat
    end if
    delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again
end repeat end tell
```

Comment: RE: "How to fix it for Chrome?" --  What have you tried? Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know the website you were targeting so I had no way of testing the code below.

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set keyword to "Authentication mail"
    repeat
        set myWindow to active tab of first window
        tell myWindow
            activate
            execute javascript "window.location.reload();"
            repeat while (execute javascript "document.readyState;") is not "complete"
                delay 0.5
            end repeat
            set pageContent to execute javascript "window.document.documentElement.outerHTML;"
            if pageContent contains keyword then
                tell current application to beep (beep (beep))
                exit repeat
            end if
            delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: RE: "I didn't know the website you were targeting so I had no way of testing the code below." -- As this _webpage_ contains the `keyword` you can test it on this page.

Comment: user3439894, Man! You are the greatest! Thank you! It works real good for regular windows/pages. But something wrong with modal windows (class="modal-open"). Do you have any ideas about modal windows and pop-ups?

Comment: @Дмитрий Чудотворец, I just made a minor edit to gurkensaas's answer, so you should be thanking gurkensaas not me. That said, please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  RE: "Do you have any ideas about modal windows and pop-ups?" --  Without out any proper context there is not much I can say. You should ask another question providing all of the relevant details.

Comment: gurkensaas, thank you so much! Guys, you are 

Comment: @ДмитрийЧудотворец If you like my answer, consider accepting it so other people searching for the same thing can find it.